# Laravel cast a field in a relationship call

Tags: php, laravel

When I call a collection of models, I sometimes cast a date field to a specific format:

```
$shifts = Shift::where('some_field', 'some_value')
    ->withLinkedShifts()
    ->withCasts([
       'date' => 'date:Y-m-d',
       ...
    ])->get();
```

The "withLinkedShifts()" scope calls a relationship called *linked_shifts* which are shift instances that are related to the instance being called. This cast works on the *date* field for the model being called, but it does not act on the *date* field of shifts in the *linked_shifts* relationship. How do I cast the dates in the *linked_shifts* relationship without having to edit the model?

Answer (score 1):

In the `linked_shifts` model itself you should indicate the date:

```
class LinkedShifts extends Model {
    protected $dates = [
        'date'
    ];

    // OR

    protected $casts = [
        'date' => 'date:Y-m-d'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! This is fine when I want to cast it each time I call that relationship, but I'm wondering if there is a way to define the cast at relationship call. E.g. if I need to provide different formats at different calls.